# Active Sheet Doesn't Change in Google Sheets Mobile App

Tags: google-apps-script, mobile, google-sheets

I'm using a spreadsheet to track my routine in the gym. I have it set up to duplicate the active sheet and name the duplicate with today's date. It's set up to trigger the below code on edit:

```
function myProgress() {
var fullDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT-5", "dd/MM/yyyy");
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
var name = fullDate;
var currentName = ss.getSheetByName(name);

if (!currentName) {
ss.insertSheet(name, {template: sheet});
ss.moveActiveSheet(1);
ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheets()[0]);
}
}
```

Which works great on desktop.

If today (28/02/2020) I edit my workout routine done on 25/02/2020, Sheet 25/02/2020 is duplicated and named "28/02/2020". Then Sheet 28/02/2020 is the active sheet.

But because of the way the mobile app works (maybe to do with the confirmation of entered text?) it will duplicate and rename the the sheet but it won't set the new one as the active sheet.

Yes, it's only a minor inconvenience to have to remember to go to today's sheet before continuing to edit, but I'd really love to work out a way around this.

Comment: Yes. I have seen that very same problem.  It's probably why I don't use mobile sheets much.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Cooper. Glad to know I'm not the only one. Usually I'd use sheets on desktop. But the out in the world use of this sheet necessitates mobile use. It's not the end of the world if I don't find a solution but it'd be nice.

Comment: I use webapps a lot and they work well for me.  They take a little more effort but I find them indispensable.

Answer (score 0):

i found a workaround like this

```
if (targetSheet) {
      // Activate the target sheet
      var targetSheetIndex = targetSheet.getIndex();
      targetSheet.activate();
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().moveActiveSheet(2);
      targetSheet.showSheet();
       
      dbsheet.hideSheet();
      dbsheet.showSheet();

      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().moveActiveSheet(targetSheetIndex);
      dbsheet.getRange("C2").clearContent();
    } else {
      Logger.log("Sheet with name '" + sheetName + "' not found.");
    }
```

this activates the sheet you want to jump to, then saves the index, and hides the sheet you are on so you land on the sheet you want to go, after that you can change back the index.
works like a charm